# What is mean by a lightweight framework?

Tags: codeigniter

What is a lightweight framework? Why it is saying that codeigniter is lightweight?

Comment: Once you search for the definition, you get why it's applied to something

Comment: It's of deliberately limited functionality, in order to be easy to learn, and/or fast (+1 to limit the -5 damage, but this is off-topic because it is subjective/discursive - please read the Help section when you get a mo!).

Comment: Editing an original question into a totally different and completely unrelated questions is not a good idea unless you don't want anybody to ever look at it

Comment: I've reverted the totally different question. If you want to ask a new question, then ask a new one rather than editing an old one. But please don't ask the one you edited into this page - it is too broad and can be answered with a web search.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a post i found on [coderanch.com](http://www.coderanch.com/t/60198/oa/Lightweight) :

> The term "lightweight" refers to the conceptual weight of a framework.
>   Lightweight frameworks like Spring have minimal impact to an
>   application. That is, it does not require as many code changes to
>   incorporate them into your application as does the more heavyweight
>   frameworks like EJB. When you create an EJB, you have to deal with
>   several interfaces and it is pretty clear by looking at the code that
>   an EJB is tightly coupled to the J2EE framework. On the other hand, a
>   POJO is usually blissfully unaware that it is being used in the Spring
>   Framework. Spring is minimally-invasive. There are also claims that it
>   should not be a very difficult task to take Spring out and replace it
>   with another similar framework.
>
> With lightweight frameworks, you do not have to think too much about
>   the underlying framework because there really isn't much code to write
>   that explicitly ties you in with the "plumbing". On the other hand,
>   traditional J2EE development with EJB entails writing a lot of
>   "plumbing" code which weighs you down conceptually.

Hope it helps.